# Ubuntu 17 System BootOrder not found

Tags: 16.04, boot

The PC is Acer with Windows 10. Bought last year and reinstalled with Ubuntu 16. I tried Ubuntu 17 after it came out. Everything was fine until I accidently used some upgrade from Software Center. Now everytime I hit the power button, it flashes:

```
System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults. 
Creating boot entry 'Boot0038' with label 'ubuntu' for file 
'\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi'. 

Reset system
```

And it immediately powers off itself and restarts to repeat the failure. I can only boot from a bootable USB-stick in legacy boot mode.

I know I shouldn't use the upgrade so carelessly but can someone help me out.

Comment: I just had the same problem - see this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053961/system-bootorder-not-found-after-installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the EFI section of partition table has lost its' boot list. Only way I know to add them is by reinstalling the whole system. Making sure Ubuntu sees your EFI boot partition. Been there, done that here too. If you can boot into windows via the cd, there are options to rebuild the MBR (mast boot record). it will put back the windows boot settings. There are cd / ISO of parition recovery systems online. I know one had a feature to "find" bootable paritions on your system. SystemRecovery CD or something like that.

Comment: Simply erased and reinstalled the whole thing. The PC is just a toy that I can mess up with.... The reinstalling didn't solve the problem (cannot find the bootable device) and I guess I didn't rebuild the MBR either. I went to the BIOS security menu and select 'shimx64.efi' as the trusted boot file. I may missed some point but this is the best I can describe. Any idea what was happening there.

Comment: Only thing I could add, is if you use a live-session usb, use gparted, and go to the "Device" menu, and create a brand new partition table. That would really start from scratch, since you have to create the EFI partition, which is always FAT32 , mine has flags set for BOOT , and ESP. Then create your root (/) and I have a separate home partition (/home/$user) so I can keep my personal stuff in case my system crashes.